# Categorizing columns from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

(I'm unable to download any modules as I'm on a school computer, lacking administrative privileges.)

I'm trying to put variables inside a CSV file into a category, so I can print them all out without hassle. E.g., Print all of the first names in a file etc.
My code;

```
import csv
array = []
counter = 0
print("FORENAME SURNAME EMAIL GENDER DATEOFBIRTH","\n")
csvfile = open("1000people.csv"); cr = csv.reader(csvfile); l = list(cr)
for line in csvfile:
    array.append(csvfile)
for csvfile in range(2):
    array = []
    array.append(csvfile)
    print(l)
```

This code separates everything inside of the file, but I'm not sure how to pick something directly and print it when desired. 
Any help regarding a way to categorize the contents of a CSV file is welcome.

Comment: Read about [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: Does your CSV file contain a header row or just the data?  How many columns does it have?  Do you want to display all of the columns? Please edit your question to show a few sample rows.